# Menú desplegable html overflow

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema en un menú desplegable.

A la hora de realizar el dropdown este no se pinta entero. He estado buscando y una solución que baraje fue modificar el atributo "overflow" de "hidden" a "visible". El resultado es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pinta el bloque pero desaparece el fondo de la etiqueta li.

Si pongo **overflow = hidden**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código para que lo podáis ver en profundidad:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

a:link.NavLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a:link.NavLink2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.NavLi1 {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 90px;
  float: left;
}

.NavLi2 {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  height: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

a:hover.NavLinkHover .dropdown-content {
  color: grey;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="dropdown NavLi1">
      <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.google.com"> Home
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Descubrir</a> </li>
    <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Login</a> </li>
    <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.altavista.com">Registrar</a> </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema de que no veas el color negro del fondo del menú es que tienes los elementos flotando, entonces salen del flujo de la página y el `ul` se queda "vacío" y pierde la altura.

Hay varias opciones de solucionar eso. Una es, como has hecho, poner un `overflow:hidden` pero al tener un menú desplegable no sirve porque queda oculto.

Otra opción es ponerle al `ul` también un `float:left`, pierde el ancho, así que tienes que declararlo:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

a:link.NavLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a:link.NavLink2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.NavLi1 {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 90px;
  float: left;
}

.NavLi2 {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  height: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

a:hover.NavLinkHover .dropdown-content {
  color: grey;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="dropdown NavLi1">
    <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.google.com"> Home
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Descubrir</a> </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Login</a> </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.altavista.com">Registrar</a> </li>
</ul>
```

También puedes quitar los float y usar `display:inline-block` en los elementos del menú:

```css
        .menu {
          background-color: black;
          font-size: 30pt;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        a:link.NavLink {
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Arial;
          color: white;
          font-size: 12pt;
          display: block;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center;
        }

        a:link.NavLink2 {
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Arial;
          color: white;
          font-size: 12pt;
          display: block;
          padding: 14px 50px;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .NavLi1 {
          display: inline;
          word-spacing: 90px;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .NavLi2 {
          display: inline;
          word-spacing: 200px;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: green;
          min-width: 160px;
          height: 100;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          padding: 12px 16px;
          z-index: 1;
        }

        a:hover.NavLinkHover .dropdown-content {
          color: grey;
          display: block;
        }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="dropdown NavLi1"><a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.google.com"> Home
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
       </div>
     </a>
  </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Descubrir</a> </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Login</a> </li>
  <li class="NavLi1"> <a class="NavLink NavLinkHover" href="http://www.altavista.com">Registrar</a> </li>
</ul>
```